# How to implement +(Class) layerClass in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

I see this in many projects that demonstrate the use of `CAEmitterLayer`, but how does it translate to MonoTouch aka Xamarin.iOS?

```
+ (Class) layerClass 
{
    //configure the UIView to have emitter layer
    return [CAEmitterLayer class];
}
```

I know I can use `UIView.Layer.AddSubLayer()` but there seems to be performance impact.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to expose it to Obj runtime like the following.

```
[Export ("layerClass")]
public static Class LayerClass () {
  return new Class (typeof (CAEmitterLayer));
}
```

For further info take a look to [MonoTouch... CATiledLayer example](http://conceptdev.blogspot.it/2010/09/monotouch-help-catiledlayer-not-quite.html).

Hope it helps.

P.S. Check the code. I've written without Xamarin Studio support.

Comment: Works! Thanks! Interestingly, the layer class does neither need an IntPtr c'tor, nor a RegisterAttribute.

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same experience with `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class.

Comment: There is a 5 min delay before an answer can be marked as correct. :-)

Comment: @Krumelur I was not aware of this. Thanks. ;)

Comment: And one more note: it really solved the performance problem. The particles are now following my finger without delay compared to a visible delay when using AddSubLayer()

Comment: @Krumelur Happy to ear this!!